# Ubuntu network not work well

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ping

My Ubuntu host network works moaning with high rate package lost. Can not ping the inner, public net, event the gateway. But with a strange situation, after disconnecting the eth0 then starts, the network is OK for a while. Then it moaning. There is other phenomenon, it can ping a Windows host pluged in the same switch device.

I check the ifconfig and route is OK.

details:
Ubuntu ip: 172.26.179.101 255.255.255.0 172.26.179.1

Windows ip: 172.26.179.37

ping 127.0.0.1 & 172.26.179.37 is OK without package lost.

ping 172.26.179.1 / 8.8.8.8 is moaning.

route -n is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.26.179.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.26.179.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: I'd suggest to check your gateway. It seems it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another network cable, replace the one you are using to connect the Ubuntu system to the gateway. Also check to make sure the speed and [duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)) settings are the same on the gateway and the network interface to the gateway on the Ubuntu system. One method for checking those settings on the Ubuntu system is with the [ethtool command](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/ethtool.html). If the utility isn't installed already you can install it with the command `sudo apt-get install ethtool`.  You could issue the command `ethtool eth0` to check the settings with that tool - see [How can I verify the speed of my NIC in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431911/how-can-i-verify-the-speed-of-my-nic-in-ubuntu) for other methods. Sometimes there can be a problem with [autonegotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) of those settings between some devices. If there is a problem with autonegotiation, [you can turn autonegotiation off on the Ubuntu system and configure the speed and duplex settings to specified values](http://Check%20to%20make%20sure%20the%20speed%20and%20duplex%20settings%20are%20the%20same%20on%20the%20gateway%20and%20the%20network%20interface%20to%20the%20gateway%20on%20the%20Ubuntu%20system.%20If%20there%20is%20a%20problem%20with%20auto%20negotiation,%20you%20can%20turn%20auto%20negotiation%20off%20on%20the%20Ubuntu%20system%20and%20configure%20them%20to%20specified%20values.).